# AttributeError: 'ModelChoiceField' object has no attribute 'specification'

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I have looked at previous questions posted and have not found an issue or a response that is applicable to my current situation.  So I am hoping that someone will read my post and help me with my **specific issue**.

A description of my issue:
I currently have a form named TestCaseStepForm.  It has a field "Requirements".  What I am trying to do is have this field only display results based on this query:

```
requirement = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=Requirement.objects.filter(specification=test_case.specification.id
    ).filter(process=test_case.process.id).filter(status='Approved'),
    widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), required=False,
    empty_label='')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kd3qe.png)

I know that the query works since I am using it to render data in an unrelated table.  It is just not filtering the data in the select field.

Any help to tell me what is wrong with my field would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you have a field for specification in your Requirement model.

Comment: Yes,     specification = models.ForeignKey(
        Specification, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='req_spec', blank=True, null=True)